# Theme Files getting include in .ics downloaded file

Tags: php, wordpress, icalendar

Im working on a simple script to include a "Add to calendar" button.
Im using the idea and ICS.php file from https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/635416 that is a old post.

Im getting the file to download through a function using add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cl_download_ics' ); [The theme is Avada]. But what is happening now is that the download invite is including the themes template file to the file that I don't want and even after removing the template code that was added extra the file still does not want to add the event to the iCalendar.

Here is the code I have so var.

```
include_once (plugin_dir_path(__DIR__).'cl-add-to-calendar/ics.php');

function cl_download_ics(){

  if (isset( $_GET['ics'])) {


    $query_data_get = $_POST;
    //$query_data = $query_data_get['calendar_data'];

    $dtstart = date_create($query_data_get['date_start']);
    $dtstart = date_format($dtstart,"Y/m/d H:i:s");

    $dtend = date_create($query_data_get['date_end']);
    $dtend = date_format($dtend,"Y/m/d H:i:s");


    header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Invite.ics');

    $ics = new ICS(array(
      'location' => $query_data_get['location'],
      'description' => $query_data_get['description'],
      'dtstart' => $dtstart,
      'dtend' => $dtend,
      'summary' => $query_data_get['summary'],
      'url' => $query_data_get['url']
    ));

    echo $ics->to_string();
  }

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cl_download_ics' );


function calendar_btn_ad($atts){

  // Shortcode atts with examples
  // dtsrart      --- 2017-1-16 9:00AM
  // dtend        --- 2017-1-16 9:00AM
  // location     --- 123 Fake St, New York, NY
  // description  --- This is my description
  // summary      --- This is my summary
  // url          --- http://example.com

  $form_input_fields = array();
  if (! empty($atts['dtsrart'])) {
    $form_input_fields[] = '<input type="hidden" name="date_start" value="'.$atts['dtsrart'].'">';
  };

  if (! empty($atts['dtend'])) {
    $form_input_fields[] = '<input type="hidden" name="date_end" value="'.$atts['dtend'].'">';
  };

  if (! empty($atts['location'])) {
    $form_input_fields[] = '<input type="hidden" name="location" value="'.$atts['location'].'">';
  };

  if (! empty($atts['description'])) {
    $form_input_fields[] = '<input type="hidden" name="description" value="'.$atts['description'].'">';
  };

  if (! empty($atts['summary'])) {
    $form_input_fields[] = '<input type="hidden" name="summary" value="'.$atts['summary'].'">';
  };

  if (! empty($atts['url'])) {
    $form_input_fields[] = '<input type="hidden" name="url" value="'.$atts['url'].'">';
  };


  $download_link = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/cl-add-to-calendar/download-ics.php';

  ob_start();
  ?>

  <form action="?ics=true" method="post">
    <?php foreach ($form_input_fields as $input_field): ?>
      <?php echo $input_field; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" id="cl-add-calendar-submit" value="Add to Calendar">
  </form>

  <div id="cl-btn-ajax-result">

  </div>

  <?php
  $output = ob_get_clean();
  return $output;
}

add_shortcode('cl_calendar_btn', 'calendar_btn_ad');
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply `exit` after you made your output?

Comment: @CBroe Also had that Idea but with the way im calling the function on form submit it is causing the site to crash, I have had the idea of changing the way the cl_download_ics function is called but not sure what the best way to do this will be so that it downloads the output at a file.

Comment: I would probably avoid having this request go through the normal routing and templating in the first place, and set up a proper custom endpoint for this. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

It is a feed, so add the feed using wordpress add_feed and your function. see
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_feed/.

```
function add_custom_feed() {
    add_feed( 'ics', 'cl_download_ics' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_feed' );
 
function cl_download_ics() {
    header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
    etc.....
}
```

I'm using custom post types for the event and adding the ics feed when I register the post type.  Adding the feed needs to be done with an early wordpress action.   Don't use theme actions.